# Searching within a list - Is there a more efficient way to write this code?

Tags: python

I have a code I wrote in Python, this is what the code does:

There's a list which contains another list in it, the code goes over the list and if it finds the letter N in the first column it needs to get the ID and date associated with it (columns 2 and 3), then it needs to look for the ID in the file again but this time it needs to have the letter F next to it and then it needs to get the date for that entry.

This is the code I wrote:

```
empty_list = []
for row in file:
    if row[0] == "N":
        id = row[1]
        date = row[2]
        date2 = 0
        for row in file:
            if row[0] == "F" and row[1] == id:
                date2 = row[2]
        empty_list.append([id,date,date2])
```

The code iterates over the entire list, when it finds the letter N in the first column it gets the id and date, it then goes over the file again and finds the same id with the letter N in the first file.

Should I have just used a find method to search for the id with the condition that the first column will be F?

Comment: Could you provide a sample of `file`

Comment: You could terate once through the file and build a dict with the id as key, and a tuple or a dict of the N and F dates as values. This will be O(n) instead of O(n^2).

Comment: The file is pretty long, but it looks something like this:

[[Jan 1st 2017, 5344443434, F],
[Feb1st 2018, 5344443434, N],
[March 2nd, 2019, 54437774, G]]

Basically the file has 3 columns: date, id and letter. The letters I needs are F and N but it can have other letters, each letter has an id next to it and the id can be repeated more than once. After I find a line with the letter N I need to find a line with the letter F and the same id.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include this information.